# Длинный заголовок

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть следующий `largeTitle` для `navigationBar`: «Длинный длинный длинный длинный заголовок». Но когда я перехожу в контроллер, я вижу что-то вроде этого: `Длинный длин...`. Я не вижу часть своего заголовка. Сначала была идея сделать заголовок в две строки. Но работающих примеров на iOS 13 я не нашел. Поэтому решил изменить размер текста заголовка:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 24)]
```

Но проблема в том, что когда захожу в свой контроллер я вижу не `largeTitle`, а обычный размер `navigationBar` который повалятся при скроллинге. Но я хочу видеть `largeTitle` когда захожу в контроллер.

Конечно же я использую это, но не помогает:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

Когда я перехожу к своему контроллеру, я вижу это:

[image]

А хочу видеть это:

[image]

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете вот так попробовать)

```
  func adjustsNavigationTitleToFitWidth() {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
    
    self.title = "Очень очень очень очень длимый текст"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
      .foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
      .font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle)
    ]
    
    for navItem in(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)! {
      for itemSubView in navItem.subviews {
        if let largeLabel = itemSubView as? UILabel {
          largeLabel.text = self.title
          largeLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        }
      }
    }
  }
```